# pandas rename_axis not taking inplace argument

Tags: pandas, in-place

I have the following code. I thought `df` should have index name of `INDEX` at the end, given I set the `inplace` argument. But that's not the case. What am I missing? Or is it a bug in Pandas?

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> df
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4
>>> df.rename_axis('INDEX', inplace=True)
       0  1
INDEX
0      1  2
1      3  4
>>> df
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4
>>>
```

Comment: I guess you'll just have to reassign `df`

Comment: Bug reported https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17317

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be straightforward. I tried it myself and experienced the same issue, so, congratulation, you've found a bug in Pandas.
Here is what you can do with your code for now:

```
>>> df = df.rename_axis('INDEX')
       0  1
INDEX
0      1  2
1      3  4
>>> df
       0  1
INDEX
0      1  2
1      3  4
>>>
```

In case you're interested to contribute to Pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/contributing.html#bug-reports-and-enhancement-requests

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug, instead of `rename_axis` you can use `index.rename` with `inplace = True` parameter.

```
df.index.rename('INDEX', inplace=True)
```

Output of df:

```
       0  1
INDEX      
0      1  2
1      3  4
```